# A/C freezing damaged air handler blower?

Tags: hvac

While I was moving, I left my front door open for at least two hours. As a result, my coils froze up outside and inside the return and the inside handler. The vents were not putting out any air and it was getting warm in the house; that's when I knew something was wrong. I immediately turned everything off.

It took 2 1/2 days to totally defrost then I turned my unit back on. Everything is running fine now although my filter was a little dirty.

My a/c man thinks I need a new blower that cost $750. If it's working again why would I need a new one?

Comment: Did the "*a/c man*" check the blower, or run any type of diagnostics on the system?

Comment: A low charge in your unit can also cause iceing. I think 700 for a new motor is high many are fractional Horse Power that if not spinning free a few drops of light oil can fix. A bad capacitor can also cause the low air flow if the filters are clean. Last a non acid coil cleaner to remove dust and oil from the coil and help it breathe

Comment: I think your "a/c man" may be right. Two hours of the front door being open seems unlikely to cause the entire system to freeze up unless there was something else going on as well (e.g. the blower running too slowly).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I am also agree with Ed Beal. how can your AC technician suggest you a new blower! a regular servicing of your unit may be the good solution for you, just clean your ac properly and you will be experience better cooling...